# openvpn - cen connect to server

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I can't connect to the test VPN server with the computer (ubuntu 19.10).
From other devices I can connect to the VPN server. Interestingly, I can connect to the VPN server from a phone that is in the same WIFI network as the laptop (ubuntu 19.10).

I create an individual certificate / config for each device.
I tested the config (.ovpn) on another laptop to make sure that the one that is used on the laptop (ubuntu 19.10). Generating a new config (.ovpn) with a different client name did not help. So this is probably not a config problem.
Of course, only one device uses each config (.ovpn) at a time.

The server operates on port 443 and TCP.
The server sees the connection attempt. Here are the logs:

```
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=19613 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=19787 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20012 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1170 EF:80 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20050 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1623 D:1450 EF:123 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20100 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1571,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_SERVER,keydir 0,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20113 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1571,tun-mtu 1500,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,keydir 1,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 256,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20160 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20177 TCP_SERVER link local: (not bound)
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=20190 TCP_SERVER link remote: [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=851748 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER READ [54] from [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #1 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=851840 5.30.2.228:53210 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210, sid=2832eb2f 088ce713
Thu Jan  9 14:45:12 2020 us=851915 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER WRITE [66] to [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #1 ] [ 0 ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:45:14 2020 us=6430 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #2 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:45:18 2020 us=624179 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #3 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:45:26 2020 us=660688 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #4 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:45:42 2020 us=538077 5.30.2.228:53210 TCP_SERVER WRITE [54] to [AF_INET]5.30.2.228:53210: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_SERVER_V2 kid=0 pid=[ #5 ] [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
Thu Jan  9 14:46:12 2020 us=236904 5.30.2.228:53210 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Jan  9 14:46:12 2020 us=237027 5.30.2.228:53210 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Thu Jan  9 14:46:12 2020 us=237271 5.30.2.228:53210 Fatal TLS error (check_tls_errors_co), restarting
Thu Jan  9 14:46:12 2020 us=237300 5.30.2.228:53210 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
Thu Jan  9 14:46:12 2020 us=237371 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
```

On laptop with ubuntu 19.10 i can see similar logs.

I conclude that this is a problem on a laptop with ubuntu 19.10, but what could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with ubuntu. It was to do with ubuntu firewall and mangle and nat table. I could not pinpoint exactly which of them causing this failure. But be careful before proceeding. It will flush your firewall and iptables. In my case, I didn't had any other dependencies on the ubuntu firewall and nat. On the client ubuntu, I flushed all the iptable, nat and iptables -

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

sudo iptables -t nat -F

sudo iptables -t mangle -F

sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -X
```

And then I run the client ovpn-

```
sudo openvpn --config clientname.ovpn
```

After that it worked. Later I added the ubuntu Firewall and iptables manually according to my need.

Also check the client config file. Check if every name like ca, cert, tls_auth these names are written correctly. For a small spelling mistake this would cause similar error.

Comment: Clearing iptables did not help